# Fixing the Permission Denied on My Localhost

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I am using Ubunto.When i browse my local host i would like to see my shared directory named myproj. now when i browse it ,this is the message i receive:

`Forbidden`

`You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

I tried:

1)giving permission to anyone on this directory and changed the owner to my current user
2) changed my conf settings to below:

Can anyone help me fixing this?

my conf settings is as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/sites-available/myproj
<Directory /myproj>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /etc/apache2/sites-available/myproj>
  Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  deny None
  allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
  AllowOverride All
  Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `tail -n 20 /var/log/apache2/error.log` Would be helpful as you have syntax errors in your config and it could be permission related.

Comment: @nesreka : i checked the path , there is 2 error logs named error.log and error.log.1 this is the output of error.log.1                                                              Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/
[Tue Feb 18 12:22:01 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/

Comment: try to replace <Directory /myproj> to <Directory /etc/apache2/sites-available/myproj> and take a look to the permission folder on your machine and don't forget to restart apache after modify the vhost

Comment: @user468891 i did the modification ,is not working still

Comment: do you have an index.php or something like this on your project? create an simple php file named index.php an put in <?php phpinfo(); ?> and browse your project

Comment: this one you say is working . the only thing is i want to see a folder in my local host not an html file , what about that?

Comment: you can just create the folder and then you will see it or set the Documentroot to one folder above.

Comment: this should be the way as i did before , but unfortunately still im not seeing it in my localhost

Answer (score 0):

In the conf you should change:

```
-Indexes
```

To:

```
Indexes
```

Then, after restarting Apache and provided that `/etc/apache2/sites-available/myproj` does not have an index.html or index.php as default document you can see the contents of that folder displayed in your browser.